# Determinant of the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How can I calculate the determinant of the inverse of a matrix using Cholesky decomposition. I have found this that it is not a good idea to directly calculate the determinant of matrix. So can anyone provide some insights?

Comment: move to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have the Cholesky decomposition (A = L * L_t), then you just have

```
det(A) = det(L) * det(L_t) = sqr(det(L))
```

The L matrix is lower triangular so its determinant is the product of diagonal elements.

The Cholesky decomposition takes O(n^3) operations and the product of diagonal elements of L is only O(n). Gaussian elimination method (convert A to triangular matrix) would take O(n^3) and would suffer from possible numerical problems.

Finally, det(inv(A)) = 1/det(A).

Comment: I think the poster is referring to the squaring operation (power of 2), not the square root operation.

Comment: sqr() is "square" (or power of 2), not sqrt() which is "square root"

Answer (score 1):

`det(A) = product(eigenvalues(A)) = product(diagonal(choleskyFactorization(A)))^2`

For example, to compute the determinant of a matrix `A` in Matlab/Octave you can use `prod(diag(chol(A)))^2`, which is the right hand side of the above equation in Matlab syntax.